# Database reading calls from spring item processor

Tags: spring, batch-processing

I am new to Spring Batch.

I just want to know whether can we make database calls(jdbccursoritemreader) from Itemprocessor?

I have a requirement to read the db(ItemReader), send the records for processing(ItemProcessor), at the time of processing I need to call other database (Just like reference data) to update the records which I got from ItemReader and finally send the final ones to writer.

Any workaround and suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this.

You would need to inject a class into your processor to do the database reading for you. I'd probably go with a JdbcTemplate for simplicity.

Something like this:

```
public class MyProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Foo, Bar> {

  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Override
  public Foo process(Bar bar) throws Exception {
    //use JdbcTemplate here
  }

  public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
  }

}
```

When you configure your processor, inject the JdbcTemplate:

```
<bean class="com.example.MyProcessor" id="myProcessor">
  <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi Neil, Thanks for your reply. I kept this solution as PLAN B. I thought whether spring batch configuration itself provides solution like this, like itemReader1 reads data from main db and sends to itemprocessor1, itemReader2 reads data from reference db and sends to itemprocessor2 and using compositeitemprocessor club both results, process and send it to single or multiple Itemwriters. Is it possible like this?